# Give a user read access to a directory without making them owner

Tags: permissions, chown

I want to give user *testuser* read access to */Media/Test* without making them the owner of the directory, nor giving access to everyone. How would I go about this?

I want to do this because I'm worried about the consequences of not being the owner of the directory (with *all* of my stuff inside) with my "personal" user. Is this justified?

Comment: You need [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs)

Comment: What is the ownership (in particular, the *group ownership*) of the /Media/Test directory?

Comment: @steeldriver the ownership of /Media/Test is morph:morph (my personal user that I use for administering the system) and I think it would be the best to keep it that way so I can't lock myself out as easily, or am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your request, not making testuser the owner, nor making it world readable, the easiest solution would be to add a seperate group (testgroup), add the testuser there, chown the directory to the group and finally chmod the directory to 750.

```
groupadd testgroup
useradd -G testgroup testuser
chown :testgroup /Media/Test
chmod 750 /Media/Test
```

If you already have files in there, you have to use `-R` switch for `chown` and `chmod` to change the files in it as well. In addition, if you add files or directories later within the directory, you have to make sure the group settings are correct (`morph:testgroup`), as long as testuser should have access to this new files. Of course you can add your own user to that group too.

```
useradd -G testgroup morph
```

Furthermore I want to add, that as long as you are root on your system -- or as long as you can use sudo --, you don't have to be worried, because you can change back every standard file permissions, as long as they are not further protected by a specific MAC (media access control) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) sytem like selinux. But I assume they aren't in your case.